# Can someone explain UINavigationController setViewController and popToViewController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I'm familiar with the idea of creating a new viewcontroller and pushing it onto the stack.  So far I have just created an instance of my view controller and pushed it.  Now I am running into a problem that my 3 different view controllers are related ways of looking at the data.  My RootViewController has 3 icons to start, and when you press on an icon, you push the first view controller.  I currently do not set the view controllers in an array since I'm not sure what that buys me or how that works.

Scenario 1: Click on icon 1 (push vc1), click on a table in a popover in vc1, it'll push to vc3.  Then you click on something in vc3, and it'll go to vc1.

Scenario 2: Click on icon 3 (push vc3), click on something and go to vc1.

So the problem I'm having is in scenario 1, it would seem to make the most sense to pop back to vc1 so they don't have a stack of vc1/vc3/vc1 and are looking at the data twice like that.  But in scenario 2, since I started at vc3 instd of vc1, I should push vc1.  But in both scenarios, the user is clicking on the same thing to go to vc1 from vc3, so how do I tell which viewController they came from in order to push or pop to vc1?

So I guess that's where I thought setViewControllers or popToViewController might come in handy, but I'm not sure how those work and if there's some simple example snippet someone can provide to get me started (assuming this approach is ok).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me, from your description, that you should be using a navigation controller that you push and pop onto and off. Btw, the navigation bar doesn't have to be visible.

It also sounds like you should sometimes pop the current vc before pushing the next vc. You will need to check the count of the viewControllers array - if the current count is greater than one then pop before pushing, otherwise just push as you are at the root view controller.

Or, you could use popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO each time before pushing.

Answer (score 1):

UINavigationController is what allows you to manage your views. 
setViewController allows you to set which controller handles your view.
popToViewController takes the current view controller off the stack to the specified view.

IMO... The last 2 promote spaghetti logic and should be used sparingly.